# Date string convertion wrong month

Tags: ios, date, swift3

I would like to convert my date from "25-12-1994" to "25-Dec-1994". But during debug the result come out like this

[image]

Below are my code:

```
 let dateStr = "25-12-1994"
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
 let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateStr)
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
 let actualDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

Comment: `dd-mm-yyyy` vs `dd-MM-yyyy`. `mm` vs `MM`. Check the doc: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns to know the difference.

Comment: @Larme I want it display MMM not MM

Comment: You need to understand: `M` (uppercase) is for Month. `m` (lowercase) is for Minutes. The number of occurence/repetition determine what to show (all letters, numbers, numbers with leading zeros, etc.), but interpret the data as month or minutes. But in your first formatter, you set to read the month as minutes. So it's writing January (default set to 1). For the first formatter, you need to write `dd-MM-yyyy`, not `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: Just change `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"` to `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"` as @Larme said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need please use below method. it will give you proper month formated date

```
func monthFormatechange(_ dateString : String) -> String
{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateString)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    let actualDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    return actualDate
}
```